# How to Stop Elmah from Logging Errors using Configuration.?

Tags: elmah

I have used Elmah for many of my web applications till date Thanks to Atif Aziz.
Now I am trying to use Elmah in one of my windows based application. Before implementing 
I m trying out some Examples and so far everything works Good.

**But Do we have any configuration which can help me stopping Elmah at once ?**

My Client doesnt want to have Elmah enabled for few of his Environment. I didnt come across 
such kind of settings in Elmah except I have heard once about ErrorEmail configuration.

**DO any one knows how to stop Elmah using configuration from logging emails ?**

Thanks in advance.